# (Rails) update_attributes throws error (needing a password) during integration test that doesn't use password

Tags: ruby-on-rails, integration-testing, update-attributes

I'm writing a Rails integration test that checks that the user's title saves. The title has one validation: it has to be no more than 255 characters. But `@user.update_attributes!(title: params[:title])` is throwing the error "Password must have at least 6 characters." But...I'm not updating the password or anything other than the title. So how do I save this attribute with its own validation and not worry about the password?

Test:

```
  test "profile submits new title and description successfully" do
    log_in_as(@non_admin)
    get user_path(@non_admin)
    assert_nil @non_admin.title
    post "/users/#{@non_admin.id}/update_description",
         { title: "I am a man of constant sorrow." }
    user = assigns(:user)
    user.reload.title
    assert user.title == "I am a man of constant sorrow."
    assert_template 'users/show'
    assert flash[:success]
  end
```

Controller method (not finished, but you'll get the idea). Note, it's the `update_attributes!` call that throws the password validation error.

```
  # Handles user's posted title and description.
  def update_description
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    # Check if title is present. If so, attempt to save, load flash, and reload.
    if @user.update_attributes!(title: params[:title])
      flash[:success] = "Saved title. "
    # if unable, set error flash and reload.
    else
      flash[:warning] = "Unable to save."
    end
    # Same logic as before, now for description.
    # Make sure two different [:success] flashes work! Probably not!
    redirect_to user_path(@user)
  end
```

Validations:

```
  validates :password, length: { minimum: 6,
                                 message: "must have at least 6 characters" }
  validates :title, length: { maximum: 255 }
```

Here's the test error:

```
23:08:51 - INFO - Running: test/integration/users_show_test.rb
Started
ERROR["test_profile_submits_new_title_and_description_successfully", UsersShowTest, 2017-10-23 01:06:11 -0400]
 test_profile_submits_new_title_and_description_successfully#UsersShowTest (1508735171.57s)
ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid:         ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Validation failed: Password must have at least 6 characters
            app/controllers/users_controller.rb:71:in `update_description'
            test/integration/users_show_test.rb:22:in `block in <class:UsersShowTest>'
        app/controllers/users_controller.rb:71:in `update_description'
        test/integration/users_show_test.rb:22:in `block in <class:UsersShowTest>'
```

In case it's relevant, here's the fixture that is loaded as `@non_admin`:

```
archer:
  name: Sterling Archer
  email: duchess@example.gov
  password_digest: <%= User.digest('Jsdfuisd8f') %>
  activated: true
  activated_at: <%= Time.zone.now %>
```

I'm a Rails noob so it's probably something basic. Thanks in advance...

UPDATE: See discussion with kasperite below. I simply needed to add `on: create` to my password validation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling `update_attributes!` will triggers `save!`, which in turn triggers validation on the model. And since you don't provide password, it will throw the exception.

You can either do `update_attribute(:title, params[:title])` which bypass validation
    or this:

```
    @user.title = params[:title]
    @user.save!(validation: false)
```

See: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence.html#method-i-update-21

Comment: Thanks for the reply!

The problem is that I'm specifically wanting to trigger this validation, but only for this attribute. I know that `update_attributes!` triggers `save!` (I want it saved to the database, that's what I'm trying to do). Is there some way to make use of only the relevant validation?

Maybe, to do an integration test, I need to prepare my fixtures differently? Let me show you the fixture above (maybe relevant?).

Comment: the only way to control when to trigger validation is in model(http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#on), I presume that's what you want

Comment: OK I've got it now. That totally fixed it: `validates :password, length: { minimum: 6, message: "must have at least 6 characters"}, on: create`

So simple. Thanks dude!